# How can I find distinct values in a list in SQL and have it returned in a list?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

wondering if there's a way I can parse a string/list in redshift for unique values and have it returned in a list/string?

For example I have a record that's like this:

| email | animal |
| --- | --- |
| ana@gmail.com | Dog, Cat, Bird, Dog, Lion, Cat |

Within the string there are duplicates but I'd like to see only the distinct values returned in list format. I'd like it to show me this:

| email | animal |
| --- | --- |
| ana@gmail.com | Dog, Cat, Bird, Lion |

Thanks!

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Why do people keep trying to do non-relational operations on relational databases? =-) have a many-to-many table and store one row per animal per email address.